# Jquery does update the sum inside the input element, but not inside the span (.val & .html)

Tags: jquery, ajax

With this code I am trying to sum the value of my checkboxes. It works only when I use the result inside an input element.

```
<input type="text" id="total1" class="container-input noborder">
```

I want the results inside the span. Like this:

```
<span class ="fsize100 bold fyellow" id="total1"></span>
```

This code works inside the input, but not inside the span.

```
$('#total1').val(total2);
```

This code shows only the sum inside the span, but it did not update the results when I check the checkboxes.

```
("#total1").html(total2);
```

This my code:

```
    $(function(){ 
$(".tot_amount").click(function(event) {
var total = 0;
$(".tot_amount:checked").each(function() {
total += parseInt($(this).val());
});
//$("#tot_amount").val(sum.toFixed(3));

$('#total1').val(total);

});

});

$(document).ready(function () {
var total2=0;
    $(".tot_amount").each(function() {
total2 += parseInt($(this).val());

});
    
$('#total1').val(total2);

//$("#total1").html(total2);
});
```

Comment: `val()` is only used for form control elements , not for content ones

Comment: Thanks. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

did you mean to bind an event to your checkboxes ?

like so

```
$('#checkbox1').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        //.. calculate something
    }       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this!

```
$('.tot_amount').click(function() {
    if($('.tot_amount').is(":checked")) {
        //do whatever
    } else {
       //do whatever
    }     
});
```